# Hi im trying to count how may words i I have in my file, but it keeps saying text 1 is not defined even though it is printed above

Tags: python

my code is trying to count how many words I have in the file which is printed above, after I wish to be able to enter a word and for the code to tell me how many of that words there are in the text and the position of it. 
2 seconds the code did not paste.

Will not let me post image so here is the code

```
         import os

os.path.isfile('text1.text')

file = open('text1.txt','r')

print(file.readline())

count = 0

with open(text1, "rb") as fp:

     data = data.translate(string>maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)

     for word in data.split():

         if word in input_list:

             count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Post your code please!

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without any real information? Show us what you have done and your file.

Comment: 1. Show us some code 2. What do you mean by position? Line number or something else?

Comment: How do I add a picture as I have under 10 reputation as I have only just joined

Comment: @tom: you don't need to. Copy the code from your editor and paste it in your question.

Comment: open(text1, "rb") as fp: should be be open("text1.text", "r") as fp:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing wrong about your code, in `os.path.isfile('text1.txt')` you're testing whether the file `text1.txt` exists. Therefore, the return value will be either True or False and not putting it within a condition is completely unnecessary and unreasonable.

Ok, now for why your code is printing correctly but not counting words. It is because the first time you open the file (`text1.txt`) you open it correctly, but on the second time you as `open` to open the file from the **variable** `text1` and as far as I can see, by the code you provided, there's no such variable. So the correct way would be something like this:

```
# pass string instead of variable
with open('text1.txt', "r") as fp:  # use only "r" as 'b' is for binary and it's a text file
    data = data.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
    for word in data.split():
        if word in input_list:
            count += 1
```

Well, additionally, I don't know where this `data.translate` came from so I can't tell if it's interfering (I don't even know if it works - it didn't work for me).